# PHP/SQL get proper array from SQL table

Tags: javascript, php, database

I got the following table in a database

```
- ID | successor 
- 01 | 02
- 01 | 04
- 01 | 08
- 02 | 03
- 04 | 05
- 05 | 06
```

This is just a simple assignment table (is this the correct english term?) for content of an E-Learning system.

My Current php code is this

```
$sqlget = "SELECT * from successor";                        
$result = $conn->query($sqlget);                                                        
$dbsuccessor = [];
    
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {                                                            
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $dbsuccessor[] = $row;                                                              
            
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
```

after parsing this to js with json_encode i get a not usefull construct like this

```
var successors = <?php echo json_encode($dbsuccessor);?>;
console.log(successor);
```

> Array[9]
>
> 0:
>
> Object ID: "1" - successor: "2"
>
> 1:
>
> Object ID: "1" - successor: "4"
>
> 2:
>
> Object ID: "1" - successor: "8"

to be fair, this is obviously exactly what you would expect with my code used above.

My goal is an array output like this:

> ID: "1" -> successor"2","4","8"

so i can see all successors of module with ID 1 when typing `console.log(successors[1]);` in javascript

best thing would be if my db table stay like it is.
How can i achieve my goal?

Comment: Please check the answers below and if any one worked for you then mark and up-vote it as an accepted answer. Up-vote others too if they are useful.

Comment: @Martin please close your question if you do not need further help.

Comment: i read that i need  reputation of 250 to close something. If this is not true, plese tell me how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Group_concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to achieve this

Change your query to

```
$sqlget = "SELECT ID,group_concat(successor) from successor group by ID";
$result = $conn->query($sqlget);                                                        
$dbsuccessor = [];

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {                                                            
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $dbsuccessor[] = $row;                                                              

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: A better answer must be appreciated.+10

Comment: thats it, thank you very much. i didnt test any other solution posted here.

Answer (score 0):

Change code that generates array to:

```
$dbsuccessor[$row['ID']][] = $row['successor'];
```